# can I use this code to create a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int arraySize;
cout << "\n\nEnter Total Number of Elements in Array.\n\n";
cin >> arraySize;
int arrayMain[arraySize];
```

I dont want to use the create "new" array command. Is the above code same as creating a new array using the new command?

Comment: No, you cannot. Use `std::vector`

Comment: it has to be an int array

Comment: @user2086751 For all intents and purposes it is.

Comment: @user2086751: C++ cannot make a dynamically-sized raw array without `new`. It's not possible, and there's pretty much no reason to want one.

Comment: To pick at nits, if you don't want to use `new`, then use a call to something in the `malloc` family.  If that doesn't work, create a huge array and manage allocations out of that array.  By far, `std::vector` is the best choice, with `new` coming in second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the above code same as creating a new array using the new command?

No, the syntax is invalid in C++. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
int arraySize;
cout << "\n\nEnter Total Number of Elements in Array.\n\n";
cin >> arraySize;
std::vector<int> arrayMain(arraySize);
```

The usage is otherwise identical.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same. Creating a dynamic-sized array with `new` is legal, your code is not. That's a pretty big difference if you ask me.

The following is though

```
std::vector<int> arrayMain(arraySize);
```

Comment: can not use vectors as this is for an assignment, but does that change anything?

Comment: so you are saying if I use my code to create a dynamic array, I wouldnt be wrong?

Comment: @user2086751 then your compiler is using a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to dynamically allocate an array in C++, and the rules of your classroom assignment enforce using built-in arrays, then you'll need the new and delete keywords:

```
int arraySize;
cout << "\n\nEnter Total Number of Elements in Array.\n\n";
cin >> arraySize;

int* arrayMain = new int[arraySize];
// use arrayMain here
delete [] arrayMain;
```

If you don't want to dynamically allocate memory, but you know a maximum, you can allocate the maximum and just not use what you don't need:

```
const int arraySizeMax = 51;
int arraySize;
do
{
  cout << "\n\nEnter Total Number of Elements in Array, no more than 50.\n\n";
  cin >> arraySize;
}
while(arraySize >= arraySizeMax);

int arrayMain[arraySizeMax];
// use arrayMain here
// No need for delete, since you didn't use new.
```

If you don't want to dynamically allocate memory and don't have a maximum, you should use a standard container like `vector`:

```
vector<int>;
```

Notice how much easier this is!  This is why you'll want to use a vector for this kind of task. (When assignments allow.)

Comment: If you want to dynamically allocate memory, then you should *still* use `std::vector`. It is only if you want to *manually* manage memory allocation that you should use an array (this should be rare).

Comment: @cjb: I changed my wording a bit, but it sounds like the assignment is to learn manual memory management.